# Distance of a specific point along a SplineCurve3 / TubeGeometry in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I'm currently trying to find the distance of a specific point along a `SplineCurve3` in Three.js. For example…

[image]

The above `SplineCurve3` has been constructed from 4 pre-defined points; a, b, c and d. To find a point along the curve I can use the [`getPoint` method in the curve class](http://threejs.org/docs/58/#Reference/Extras.Core/Curve) and provide a value (`t`) along the curve (between 0 – the start [a] – and 1 – the end [d]).

The problem I have is that I need to find the `t` value of the intermediate points (b and c) that were used to construct the curve.

Effectively, I want to do the reverse of `getPoint`. I want to pass a point along the path and be given the `t` (distance) from the beginning.

How can I do this? I just can't work it out!

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Just wondering how do you know that the given point will be on the spline curve?

Comment: Good question. I'm assuming that it will due to the given points being the original points used to create the curve in the first place. Eg. The points passed to `SplineCurve3`.

Comment: So if the given point you are searching is part of the original set used to construct the curve, then @zz85 provided you with answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my memory serves me correctly, `SplineCurve3` is a catmull-rom spline, which means the t values at a=0, b=1/3, c=2/3, d=3/3.

This generalized formula as in the source is `t = (point number) / (number of points - 1)`
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/extras/curves/SplineCurve3.js#L19

Comment: Thank you, this was just the explanation I needed!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a reverse of get_point (of course it is possible), but maybe you can create SplineCurve3 where the last point is the one you are looking for length and then simple get length of it. Then u can compare this new length with the original to get [0..1] value. If this solution does not reward you i can check the sources spline.

Comment: You might be on to something here. Could you give me a better explanation using the letters from the illustration in the original message, it would help me grasp the concept. Thanks!

Comment: @zz85 is right. I thought you'd need to calculate the value of t for any point of a curve